# Evitar la repetición del fondo gradient

Tags: css

Estoy tratando de colocar un un fondo a mi página web ¿Cómo evito la repetición del fondo gradient, en mi página? ya que lo que deseo es que los colores se vean uniformes y no con saltos.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <style>
    .fondo {
      background: no - repeat;
      background: -webkit - linear - gradient(#fff, #666 25%);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background: linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="fondo">
  <p>El lenguaje HTML es <strong>tan sencillo</strong> que prácticamente se entiende sin estudiar el significado de sus etiquetas principales.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sube todo el codigo amigo, html y css para ayudarte mejor y si puedes explicarte mejor

Comment: cuando ejecuto fragmento de coidgo no aparece nada, revisa eso por favor, que este subiendo el html y css bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución va a depender de cómo quieras resolver el problema: ¿quieres que se repita una sola vez ocupando toda la ventana o sólo el tamaño específico del contenedor?

El principal problema es que estás definiendo todo como `background`, entonces el navegador tomará la última que sea válida y la aplicará, ignorando entonces el `background: no-repeat` que tienes al principio. La solución es simple: mueve esa regla al final, y hazla más específica (`background-repeat: no-repeat`).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <style>
    .fondo {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #666 25%);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background: linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="fondo">
  <p>El lenguaje HTML es <strong>tan sencillo</strong> que prácticamente se entiende sin estudiar el significado de sus etiquetas principales.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Si en cambio lo que quieres es que sólo se repita una vez y ocupe todo el alto/ancho del contenedor, podrías hacerlo usando la propiedad `background-attachment` y asignándole el valor `fixed` (aunque se verá estirado):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <style>
    .fondo {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #666 25%);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background: linear-gradient(# fff, #666 25%);
      background-attachment:fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="fondo">
  <p>El lenguaje HTML es <strong>tan sencillo</strong> que prácticamente se entiende sin estudiar el significado de sus etiquetas principales.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que primero debes corregir el CSS:

```css
html {
    height: 100%; /*Asignar un alto al html de 100%*/
}
body {
    height: 100%; /*Tambien al Body 100%*/
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Evita que se repita*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
     background: rgba(226,226,226,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(226,226,226,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(219,219,219,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(209,209,209,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(254,254,254,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe', GradientType=0 );
    }
```

Yo me apoye del sitio: [Generador Gradientes CSS](http://www.cssmatic.com/es/gradient-generator) para el Gradiente